# Wordpress on docker compose and nginx and subpath keep logging out

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am trying to setup a wordpress on using docker-compose and nginx on a `/blog` path. I have managed to do the setup and when I connect on `http://localhost/blog/wp-login.php` I get redirected to `http://localhost/blog//wp-admin/`. Now wherever I click on the page, I get redirected back to the login page. I've tried different combinaison in `nginx.conf` but to no avail.

My `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'

services:
  db_wordpress:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db_wordpress
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db_wordpress:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |
        define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/blog');
        define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/blog');
        $$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/blog' . $$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - wordpress
    volumes:
      - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
      - ./nginx.local.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

volumes:
    db_data:
```

And my `nginx.conf`

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  upstream wordpress {
    server wordpress:80;
  }

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  sendfile on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;

  server_names_hash_bucket_size 512;

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    location /blog {
      proxy_pass http://wordpress/;
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_redirect  off;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try using: `location /blog/` { ... }`